# Reinstall Visual Studio 2015 after installing Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I was running Visual Studio 2015, and upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 around a month ago, then uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 as I was very low on HDD space at the time.

I've since joined a new project and new product team at work, and their standard development environment is Visual Studio 2015 - I feel like I should adhere to this standard as I wouldn't want any unforseen issues to arise?

Will there be any problems or concerns if I reinstall Visual Studio 2015 now? Will it cause issues in general, or when re-opening the solution which I've already opened/saved/compiled in Visual Studio 2017

I've since upgraded my SSD so space is no longer an issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Using Windows 10 (on VMWare Fusion)

Comment: Why is this marked with C#??

Comment: @MetaColon because I assumed one of the consequences of using a different version of Visual Studio might be different language versions of C#.

Answer (score 3):

There should not be any issues installing VS 2015 (or any other older issue) after you have VS 2017 installed. They are designed to be able to run concurrently.

VS 2017 can be run in VS 2015 compatibility mode. Just [set the targeting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/24/stuck-on-an-older-toolset-version-move-to-visual-studio-2015-without-upgrading-your-toolset/) in the solution in 2017 to 2015 and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

A project created in VS 2017 might not COMPLETELY be compatible with VS2015. Compents such as the sql server might become a cause of concern.
I can say this because i faced a similar problem a few days ago, though I downgraded to VS 2013 Community and not VS2015. Before you move your project to 2013 make sure you have a backup and do not uninstall VS2017 untill you're sure that the project is working fine in VS 2015